# flex 4 tooltip for tabbar

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I need to create a tooltip for tabbar how to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After creation is complete you can do this:

```
var button:ButtonBarButton = myTabBar.dataGroup.getElementAt(i) as ButtonBarButton;
button.toolTip = "Magic!";
```

Where "i" is the index of the tab you want to add the tooltip to.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hi wade, i am using tabbar with viewstack can you expline this combination?

Comment: If you are asking about the tooltips on the tabbar, all you need to do is make sure your tabbar has an id set and then you can set the tooltips as explained above.  If you are asking about using tabbars with viewstacks, I'd recommend creating a new question so we can understand the situation better.

Comment: hi wade,Thanks for your response.here i attched the code i need to show the tool tip of the tabbar how to do?                   <mx:VBox height="50%" width="50%">
<s:TabBar height="46" width="50%" id="sampleTab" dataProvider="{viewstack1}"  visible="true"/>
<mx:ViewStack id="viewstack1" width="100%" height="100%">
<s:NavigatorContent label="Tab1" toolTip="Tab1"  width="100%" height="100%">
<s:Label text="Tab1"/>
</s:NavigatorContent>
<s:NavigatorContent label="Tab2" toolTip="Tab2" width="100%" height="100%">
<s:Label text="Tab2"/>
</s:NavigatorContent>
</mx:ViewStack>
</mx:VBox>